# Is there a workaround for Google Visualization 'animationstart' for Line Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a page with multiple charts of various types, all working great with one exception. One of them is a line chart, which is a type of chart that can be animated. When the user selects a new date range for the line chart, I can open a "loading" overlay and spinner while the app gets new data, all good. The problem is I want to close this overlay when the animation starts, and but there is no `animationstart` event (that I have found.)

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#events

I can close the animation on `animationfinish`, but the effect is that the (beautifully executed) animation occurs behind the spinner and overlay. One would think I could close the "loading" overlay when the data is fetched (which I can do,) but the problem with that is if the animated chart doesn't need to fetch new data, as in filtering the current time range, the "loading" overlay would never close.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can execute an action on `animationstart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a `MutationObserver`...

once the animation starts, the observer will start reporting changes to the chart's container.

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart');
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

// mutation observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
  // close overlay
});
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

keep in mind, the observer's function will continue to be called as the animation plays out.
check to see if the overlay is open, if so, close it. otherwise, do nothing...